# Importing OSM data to pgRouting enabled database including turn restrictions

Tags: python, openstreetmap, pgrouting, routing, osm2pgrouting

I recently used the tool [pypgroutingloader](https://github.com/danieluct/pypgroutingloader) to import OSM data into a pgRouting database. For a small amount of data, this tool works perfectly. Most routing restrictions are present and it modifies the costs of various different road types right during the import. After adjusting the underlying speed profile, I was quite impressed by the results of the pgr_trsp() function!

Then I tried to load some more OSM data into a database (a whole country). The python-script easily eats up all my RAM (16 GB) and crashes within minutes. This happens even for medium large parts. Furthermore it is not possible to execute the script incrementally using smaller parts. The script is not able to merge nodes with the same OSM ID. It internally assigns new unique IDs (starting from gid = 1 every time). Since I'm completely new to python programming, I'm not able to rewrite the script in a way to make this possible.

**Is there any tool with similar capabilities?** (turn restrictions + "speed profile")

If not, how could one achieve similar results using other tools, like osm2pgrouting?